# Differential forms and wedge product and exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Could anyone help me with some easy examples of differential forms and wedge products? What I have worked out so far: an $n$-form is anything that can be integrated. An example of a one form would be $f(x)dx $ where $f$ could be a continuous function defined on a compact $1$-manifold. For $n>1$ I'm already not sure what's going on: would a $2$-form be $f$ continuous and defined on a $2$-manifold?

The wedge product is also troubling me. From what I read on Wikipedia it is like the differential area or volume: On a surface where $dx$ and $dy$ could be tangent vectors (of infinitesimal lenght) at a point then the wedge product $dx \wedge dy$ would be a parallelogram. Similarly for $3$ dimensions. I'm not sure what I've written so far is correct. But even if it was again I run into trouble [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Examples): I can't make sense of the expression $d \sigma = d(u) \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2$. Could someone shed some light please? What is $\sigma$? And what is $u$ and what is $d(u)$? And why are the indexes written as $x^i$ rather than $x_i$? Does it have any significance?

Comment: There is a text by Bachmann, freely available online, called *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms*. This may help. You can find it here: http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/ozturk/eskiders/fall04math488/bachman.pdf

Comment: @EricAuld Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Dead link above, but see: http://www.math.uqam.ca/~powell/Bachman_Geometric_Approach_to_Differential_Forms.pdf